# Node-Soap - throwing fault in async method

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-soap

Created a soap api with the node-soap library but when i try to throw a fault using

```
throw {
    Fault: {
      Code: {
        Value: 'soap:Sender',
        Subcode: { value: 'rpc:BadArguments' }
      },
      Reason: { Text: 'Processing Error' }
    }
  };
```

as descibed in the library i get a

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

this is what i am currently doing

```
                     ssm.decrypt(args.request, password, base_key)
                        .then(function (res) {
                            console.log(res)
                            parseString(res, async function (err, result) {
                                if (err) {
                               //the throws causes the error
                                    throw {
                                        Fault: {
                                            error: {
                                                data: {
                                                    error
                                                } //Error object from catch
                                            }
                                        }

                                    };
                                } else {
                                 //some code
                                }
```

thanks

Comment: Never pass an `async function` as a callback. Get a promise back from `parseString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys for your help but I got the issue

if an async function is been used for the soap api been implemented with [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

communication need to be done via callbacks

i changed the throw to

```
                                                   callback({
                                                        Fault: {
                                                            error: {
                                                                data: {
                                                                    error
                                                                } 
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                    });
```

and it works perfectly

i found it here [node-soap doc](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soaplistenserver-path-services-wsdl---create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services)

Comment: Have you checked the `Client.methodAsync(args, options)`[example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#example)? 
I'm trying to use it, but I guess that callbacks are intended for the "regular" example, the async version is supposed to return a `Promise` (ideally)

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error inside the async function

```
parseString(res, async function (err, result)...
```

rejects the promise returned by the async function - for which there is no catch handler. If `parseString` calls its callback synchronously, you could just remove the `async` declaration leaving the call as

```
 parseString(res, function (err, result)...
```

If parseString is asynchronous, however, it needs to be promisified so errors can be worked into the surrounding promise chain. As an untested example:

```
function doParseString( res) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject) {
        parseSting( res, function( err, result) {
             err ? reject( err) : resolve( result);
        });  
    });
}
```

which could be used along the lines of

```
ssm.decrypt(args.request, password, base_key)
.then( doParseString)
.then( function  (result) {
     // some code
 })
.catch( console.log);   // do something with the error
```